# Interesting negative decimal number notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was studying logarithms, and had to solve the problem:

> If $\log 8 = 0.90$, find $\log 0.125$.

I found out the answer to be $-0.90$. That was easy. But my text book has given the answer as:

$$-0.90 = \bar{1}.10$$

Now what that bar above $1$ is for ? My understanding is that it is used to signify a repeating digit. But how can $-0.90 = \bar{1}.10$ ?

Can someone please explain this to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Which text book is this? Looks like very strange notation to me...

Comment: @5xum [This](http://www.flipkart.com/concise-mathematics-i-c-s-e-march-2014-examination-part-class-ix/p/itmdgzjegbjtj7wq)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was a very common notation when decimal logarithms were involved. The starting point is that if
$$
M/N=10^k
$$
for two positive numbers $M$ and $N$, then their decimal logarithms have the same *mantissa* (fractional part) and we can write
$$
\log_{10} M= k + \log_{10} N
$$
In particular, any number $M>0$ can be uniquely written as
$$
M=10^k N
$$
with integer $k$ and $1\le N<10$. So the logarithmic tables were compiled, say, for numbers from $1$ to $1000$, but only showed the mantissa; when the logarithm of, say, $10.4$ was needed, one looked at $104$ finding the mantissa to be $01703$ and so could conclude $\log_{10}10.4=1.01703$. If one knows the decimal logarithm of $2$
$$
\log_{10}2=0.30103
$$
(equality is meant as “approximate”), then $\log_{10}0.02=-2+0.30103$, which was written as
$$
\log_{10}0.02=\overline{2}.30103
$$
to ease lookup in logarithmic tables, because, as already said, only mantissas were shown.

In your case, $0.125=1/8$, so 
$$
\log_{10}0.125=-\log_{10}8 = -3\log_{10}2=-0.90309=-1+0.09691=\overline{1}.09691
$$
(use the “complement to $9$” rule for writing the mantissa).

Comment: where you say the equality is "approximate", you can actually use the $\LaTeX$ symbol. May I edit?(+1)

Comment: @Sabyasachi I preferred the notation that was standard when doing those computations.

Comment: Okay. Cheers.${}$

Comment: @egreg Wonderful answer! Thank you! But I was wondering if at the last, it should be $-0.90309$ instead of $0.90309$ ??

Comment: @GaurangTandon You're right, I forgot the sign!

Comment: Pronounced "bar one point zero nine six nine one". I don't imagine that anybody prints log tables any more. No loss!

Comment: @TonyK Thanks; in my language, Italian, it was *uno segnato virgola zero nove sei nove uno*. We did many computations with table lookups during our third year of high school.

Comment: @GaurangTandon just to be clear for others who may be reading this $0.9691=\log_{10} 1.25$ so the expression given by egreg is the logarithm of $1.25 \times 10^{-1}=0.125$. The notation was used because it allowed easier computation in the days before computers and calculators (and also made sense in the era of slide rules).

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you!